# border on the bottom of terminal emulators even in monocle view

Tags: dwm

Edit: The border on the bottom is not set my me. i don't have it in my config.h file. To be honest wouldn't know how to set it.

so, it doesn't happen with any other programs, just terminal emulators. in all of xterm, urxvt, st, and xfce4-terminal. [image]

Edit: I want to get rid of this empty space. is there a patch or some setting i can tweak to avoid that? again, it only appears when the client is terminal emulator. not with any of firefox, pcmanfm etc.

Comment: oh sorry, i wasn't clear enough.

Comment: common now, that is a typo. border on the bottom! as you see in the pic. (the non-white line is part of wallpaper below the terminal window.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most application windows (firefox, pcmanfm, libre office, etc) allow you to resize them in pixels.

Most (all?) terminal emulators only allow you to resize them in characters - e.g. 80x24.

On my XFCE system (with a 2560x1440 screen), I have a top panel (menus, short-cut icons, some status displays) and a bottom panel (taskbar, desktop switcher, status bar, etc).  Between those two, I can fit a terminal window  that is 192 characters wide by 51 characters high.  There is a small area (maybe 4 or 5 pixels) that is not covered by the terminal window.

The combination of my font setting "Monospace Regular" @ 16pt and 192x51 characters requires 2513 pixels by 1336 pixels (so says `xwininfo`).  The handful of extra pixels is **not enough** to have an extra line (if there was, I would use it).

Comment: that was exactly it. i reduced the font size to  to 2pt just to check. the gap reduces noticeably. thanks for clearing that up.